# What software of up to 20 $ / month to protect a PC and online accounts and activities?

Tags: security

I'm looking for IT protection software. I'm developing a YouTube project and nearing the launch of the channel but I have concerns of  being hacked or doxed. When I read articles on IT protection software, I can't seep through the noise of IT terminology and end up not knowing what to look for further.

Basically I'm looking for multiple pieces of software - free - or up to 20 $ / month all together, to protect as many vulnerabilities as possible.
Online accounts, 
 email, 
 personal information, 
 browsing data, 
 personal files and any vulnerable aspect I may be forgetting.

I don't use any apps or any mobile devices and almost any software apart from two programs for animation and video production on a PC and the usual necessities like email and skype. I don't have any social media channels apart from a test channel on YouTube. I have less than 10 accounts on the same number of platforms / online services.

I am willing to employ anything and everything which would protect me from hacking or doxing for up to 20 $ / month all together.

I would be sincerely grateful for suggestions.

Comment: If it's a severe case of paranoia then simply disconnect your production station and have it offline. Disable USB ports and all of that autorun stuff. Additionally, disable services you don't need. Otherwise I recommend HIPS software as they are passive and don't waste your resources like anti viruses do.  It all comes down to whether you are a target or which sites or network you visit with that particular machine.

Comment: For online accounts, you can enable two factor authentication. And don't use those Cloud Password managers for storing your passwords. Rather forget and reset your password than have someone keep it for you. A lot of things will come with experience and hopefully nothing bad will happen. As for doxing prevention, just make sure to minimize or absolutely wipe your online footprint. The truth is nobody has control over that since information will get cached by spiders and other net critters. Location & tracking services through various apps can bring you out in the open.

Comment: The sad truth is, if THEY want to find you, THEY will find you.

Comment: Apart from paranoia: What OS should it run on?

Comment: Thank you for all the replies! Well yes, a little bit of paranoia due to a lack of skills when it comes to IT in general. I know I can be found, I just want to make it a bit harder. Basically I don't want my humble beginnings be any more humble than they have to be. I'm just looking for things anyone should if they wrote and produced material for 11 months, and basically created 3 (what I think are) high concept procedural shows for YouTube. It should run on windows 10. Should I use a VPN and encrypted email? Is two "factor authentication" two step verification as they call it on YouTube?

Comment: I know very well that anonymity is not possible and that it depends on the resources of the entity looking. I just want to do something so I won't have regrets later if something happens which I could perhaps prevent with accessible software. The reason I'm confused is that I know that money doesn't necessarily translate to better security with so many different products and services. Basically I would feel comfortable if I employed software for which I knew it came as a recommendation from someone who really knows about the field and about the latest tech. I think I'm on the right track...

Comment: Thank you for all the advice! I will look in to HIPS software you mentioned...